# Why is NumPy's `repmat` faster than `kron` to repeat blocks of arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, kronecker-product

Why is the `repmat` function from `numpy.matlib` so much faster than `numpy.kron` (i.e., Kronecker Product) to repeat blocks of matrices?

A MWE would be:

```
test_N = 1000
test_vec = np.random.rand(test_N, 2)
rep_vec = np.matlib.repmat(test_vec, 100, 1)
kron_vec = kron(ones((100,1)), test_vec)

%%timeit
rep_vec = np.matlib.repmat(test_vec, 10, 1)
53.5 µs ± 2.42 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%%timeit
kron_vec = kron(test_vec, ones((10,1)))
1.65 ms ± 228 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Both are python code which you can examine.  A quick glance shows that `repmat` uses `reshape` and `repeat`.  `kron` uses `outer` (multiply) and `concatenate`.

Comment: It isn't obvious to me why `reshape` and `repeat` would be more efficient than `outer` and `concatenate`. I think that's the point... Also, even though both are Python code I can examine, I believe the answer to this is related to how NumPy is built on C.

Comment: `np.tile(test_vec,(100,1))` is even faster.

Comment: `test_vec[None,:,:].repeat(100,0).reshape(-1,2)` is doing the same thing as `tile`.

Answer (score 1):

Some of my own timings:

```
In [361]: timeit kron_vec = np.kron(np.ones((10,1)), test_vec)
131 µs ± 871 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Your

```
kron_vec = kron(test_vec, ones((10,1)))
1.65 ms
```

looks more like a `ones((100,1))` time test.

Mine is longer than others, but not as drastically so.

A similar multiplication approach (like the `outer` of `kron`, but no need for the `concatenate` step):

```
In [362]: timeit (test_vec*np.ones((10,1,1))).reshape(-1,2)
61.2 µs ± 38.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

`repmat`:

```
In [363]: timeit rep_vec = matlib.repmat(test_vec,10,1)
94.2 µs ± 32.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Using `tile` instead:

```
In [364]: timeit np.tile(test_vec,(10,1))
20.4 µs ± 17.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

and `repeat` directly:

```
In [365]: timeit x = test_vec[None,:,:].repeat(10,0).reshape(-1,2)
12.2 µs ± 371 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: I did `%%timeit 
kron_vec_2 = np.kron(np.ones((10,1)), test_vec)` and got `61.6 µs ± 3.29 µs per loop`. However, note that `np.kron(np.ones((10,1)), test_vec)` is not the same as `np.kron( test_vec, np.ones((10,1)))`.

Comment: Also, your last two solutions do present a drastic efficiency improvement in my opinion, since these operations will be performed repeatedly on large matrices (and then absolute differences of performance start mattering more).