# Why import numpy doesn't automatically include matlib

Tags: numpy, matrix, python-import

I'm trying to repeat a numpy array x horizontally using `a=numpy.matlib.repmat(x,1,3)`. However, directly typing this results in error. I must add `import numpy.matlib` in order for `a=numpy.matlib.repmat(x,1,3)` to work.

My question is, why do I need to explicitly import `numpy.matlib`? I thought `import numpy` should automatically import everything that appears in the form `numpy.*` just like `numpy.zeros`, `numpy.array` and `numpy.mean`.

Comment: Look at the `matlib.py` file.  There's a comment: `Importing from numpy.matlib is deprecated since 1.19.0.`.  Except for thie `repmat`, is just contains versions regular `numpy` functions that return `np.matrix` type objects.  And `repmat` isn't that special either.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70466072/why-is-numpys-repmat-faster-than-kron-to-repeat-blocks-of-arrays/70468505#70468505

Comment: @hpaulj I see. Thank you very much!